# GSON parsing in android

Tags: android, gson

This is the response that i get from the server

```
{"response":{"status":"SUCCESS","errorCode":"0000","errorMessage":"Success","resultType":"WallPost","result":[{"bookmark":{},"comments":[],"createdOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":14,"minutes":0,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":0,"time":1394200800000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"event":{},"fileContentType":"","fileName":"","fileSize":0.0,"fileUrl":"","hasFile":0,"image":{},"isCommented":0,"isLike":false,"isOnlyMe":false,"isPolled":false,"isRsvp":false,"isSpamed":0,"ismoderated":0,"keywords":[],"meetingId":0,"modifiedOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":14,"minutes":0,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":0,"time":1394200800000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"originalId":0,"parentId":0,"parentPost":"","parentPostCreatedOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":14,"minutes":0,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":0,"time":1394200800000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"parentPostUserEmailAddress":"","parentPostUserId":0,"parentPostUserName":"","pollOptions":[],"post":"Hi All,~|~~|~We have provided MMv3 User Guide on below location~|~URL: http:\/\/mmv3.qlc.co.in\/ms\/MMv3_Help\/MailServe_v3.00.html~|~~|~Please provide us your suggestions and feedback.","postId":39629,"postShareWithId":[],"postType":1,"postUserId":100021,"postVisibility":0,"selectedPollOption":0,"selectedRsvp":0,"sourceId":449,"sourceName":"All QLC","sourceType":2,"tag":[],"tagId":[],"tags":" ","user":{"address":"","blogSiteUrl":"","certificates":"","college":"","connectionCount":0,"created":{},"description":"","emailAddress":"ashwini.nimbargi@qlc.in","facebookProfile":"","firstName":"Ashwini","groupCount":0,"highestDegree":"","id":0,"lastName":"Nimbargi","linkedInProfile":"","locationId":0,"mobileNumber":0,"modified":{},"nickName":"Ashwini Nimbargi","otherPhone":0,"password":"","pinCode":0,"previousEmployer":"","twitterProfile":"","type":0,"university":"","userCommunityId":0,"userId":100021,"userPreference":{},"website":""},"userFile":{},"video":{},"wallPostSummary":{"commentCount":0,"likeCount":4,"modifiedOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":14,"minutes":0,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":0,"time":1394200800000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"postId":39629,"spamCount":0,"wallPostSummaryId":29777}},{"bookmark":{},"comments":[],"createdOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":12,"minutes":44,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":31,"time":1394196271000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"event":{},"fileContentType":"","fileName":"","fileSize":0.0,"fileUrl":"","hasFile":0,"image":{},"isCommented":0,"isLike":false,"isOnlyMe":false,"isPolled":false,"isRsvp":false,"isSpamed":0,"ismoderated":0,"keywords":[],"meetingId":0,"modifiedOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":12,"minutes":44,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":31,"time":1394196271000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"originalId":0,"parentId":0,"parentPost":"","parentPostCreatedOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":12,"minutes":44,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":31,"time":1394196271000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"parentPostUserEmailAddress":"","parentPostUserId":0,"parentPostUserName":"","pollOptions":[],"post":"t","postId":39627,"postShareWithId":[],"postType":1,"postUserId":100220,"postVisibility":0,"selectedPollOption":0,"selectedRsvp":0,"sourceId":449,"sourceName":"All QLC","sourceType":2,"tag":[],"tagId":[],"tags":" ","user":{"address":"","blogSiteUrl":"","certificates":"","college":"","connectionCount":0,"created":{},"description":"","emailAddress":"pankaj.sharma@qlc.in","facebookProfile":"","firstName":"Pankaj","groupCount":0,"highestDegree":"","id":0,"lastName":"Sharma","linkedInProfile":"","locationId":0,"mobileNumber":0,"modified":{},"nickName":"Pankaj Sharma","otherPhone":0,"password":"","pinCode":0,"previousEmployer":"","twitterProfile":"","type":0,"university":"","userCommunityId":0,"userId":100220,"userPreference":{},"website":""},"userFile":{},"video":{},"wallPostSummary":{"commentCount":0,"likeCount":0,"modifiedOn":{"date":7,"day":5,"hours":12,"minutes":44,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":31,"time":1394196271000,"timezoneOffset":0,"year":114},"postId":39627,"spamCount":0,"wallPostSummaryId":29775}},{"bookmark":{},"comments":[],"createdOn":{"date":6,"day"
```

here is the java code that i use to parse it to an object

```
// this line prints the above response
Log.e(TAG, responseEntity.getBody().toString());

            Response fromJson = gson.fromJson(responseEntity.getBody()
                    .toString(), Response.class);

            Log.e(TAG, fromJson.toString());

//the above Log.e prints this Response [status=null, errorCode=null, errorMessage=null, resultType=null, result=null]
```

here is the Response Model class that i have used

```
public class Response {

    private String status;
    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String resultType;

    private Object result;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response [status=" + status + ", errorCode=" + errorCode
                + ", errorMessage=" + errorMessage + ", resultType="
                + resultType + ", result=" + result + "]";
    }

}
```

Why do I get null every time? there is no

Comment: Check if you have overridden the toString method

Comment: is that your complete response? the parser must be giving you an error in that case, something like: Parse error on line 333:

Comment: The JSON you have posted is incomplete, can you please post the whole string ? Also show your Response class!

Comment: also post Response.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one more class:

```
public class ServerResponse{

private Response response;

//get and set
}
```

Try to parse this class view GSON

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317818/malformed-json-syntax-exception-android i tried to parse it via gson and got the error.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Define annotations in Response class

```
   public class Response {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("errorCode")
    private String errorCode;
    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    private String errorMessage;
    @SerializedName("Success")
    private String resultType;

    private Object result;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response [status=" + status + ", errorCode=" + errorCode
                + ", errorMessage=" + errorMessage + ", resultType="
                + resultType + ", result=" + result + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't necessary unless the class is being obfuscated (in which case you should generally prefer removing the obfuscation, as it lowers the possibility of errors like putting `@SerializedName("Success")` on `private String resultType`).